# how to display array values in a list using ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an array

```
 {"count":3,"rows":[{"p_id":"P1","gender":"M","patient_name":"a"},{"p_id":"D1","gender":"M","patient_name":"Davin"},{"p_id":"M1","gender":"M","patient_name":"Marv"}]}
```

Which I render from my express to my `ejs` file. I have  a profile card in which I need to display each string in list. so for 3 strings 3 cards.

my `ejs` file:

```
 <ul>
     <% for(var i= 0 ; i < userData.length; i++) {%>
         <li>
             <span><%=userData[i].count %>
         </li>
         <ul>
             <% for(var j=0 ; j < userData[i].rows.length; j++) {%>
                 <li>
                     <span><%=userData[i].rows[j].p_id %>
                 </li>
             <% } %>
         </ul>
     <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined how you're rendering the EJS file so I'm going to guess that it's correct.

I'd suggest using the `.forEach(...)` function when looping through an array. See example below.

```html
<% if (locals.userData) { %> <!-- Make sure userData is defined -->
    <ul>
        <% userData.forEach(user => { %> <!-- Loop through the array -->
            <li>
                <span><%= user.count %>
            </li>
            <ul>
                <% user.rows.forEach(row => { %> <!-- Loop through the rows -->
                    <li>
                        <span><%= row.p_id %>
                    </li>
                <% }); %>
            </ul>
        <% }); %>
    </ul>
<% } %>
```

Comment: res.render('dash',{userData:a})    this is how i rendering it. where a is  var a = JSON.stringify(data).

Comment: @fungusblacky If this answer was the solution to your question, please mark it as the correct solution by clicking the tick next to the post.

Comment: NO BRO IM GETTING THIS ERROR     
    86|           <ul>
 >> 87|               <% userData.forEach(user => { %> 
    88|                   <li>
    89|                       <span><%= user.count %>
    90|                   </li>

userData.forEach is not a function

Comment: @fungusblacky In that case, the data being sent is not an array.